# Simple Way to Have Static Local IP with VPN

Tags: 16.04, openvpn, minecraft

I am trying to find a simple solution to have a static "Local" IP Address with Ubuntu 16.04 and Open VPN. Every time I use the VPN the IP Adress changes from 10.36.10.10 to some other random IP address and I want to run a Minecraft Server from my PC while still being hidden in a VPN. I'm really not sure if this is even possible or secure but changing the Address of the server at each VPN activation is certainly not going to work. Any Help is appreciated! I have figured out a way to Have PIA VPN assign a Static External IP Address but the Minecraft Client does not recognize this Address when trying to connect to the Server, (I'm assuming it's a Port Issue) but in my region, assigning a Port is not available, I must use a VPN Server in Canada which will ruin the game PING.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't do what you want to do.

The VPN provider automatically assigns you an IP. You can not change this; the provider will have to change this. They probably won't, because they're selling volume.

Second, you **need** to accept incoming connections, preferably on designated ports. PIA offers you incoming connections *on a random port*. They can (in some regions) forward a single, random, port to you. This won't cut it for you, as games commonly are expected to be present at a pre-defined port that does not change.

So in short, you can't do what you're trying to do with PIA. You can set up your own VPN tunnell from for instance AWS, where you control both ends.

Comment: PIA is assigning the "Local IP Address" of 10.36.10.10? That is not the IP that shows up when I type in Google "WhatsmyIP". But if I use that "local IP" I can access the game and my apache webpage.

Comment: PIA uses NAT. It's not reachable from the internet, and it's not a 1:1 mapping between a public IP and a private IP afaik.

Comment: I think just because I am "local" is the only reason the "local address" resolves for me, the same as if I typed 192.168.1.114?

Comment: Correct. You can read more at [wikipedia's private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) article.